# Hot Cross Bun Paradox

Tags: nursery-rhyme

In the nursery rhyme Hot Cross Buns, there's the line

> One a penny, two a penny, hot cross buns

Does this mean that you can buy a hot cross bun for either 1p or 0.5p? If so, why would anyone buy only one bun?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No paradox involved. Hot cross buns were traditionally consumed at the end of Lent, and the nursery rhyme derives from the cries of street vendors. For example:

> Hot cross buns, hot cross buns;
> One a penny poker,
> Two a penny tongs,
> Three a penny fire shovel,
> Hot cross buns.

Presumably, a one-penny bun was of better quality (or simply larger) than a half-penny bun. Going by the comparisons with fireside implements in the above street-cry, my guess is that it would be the quality that varies.

- Poker -- used to stoke a fire, and therefore relatively clean.
- Tongs -- used to handle coals and therefore likely to be contaminated with coal dust.
- Fire shovel -- used to remove the ashes from the grate of a fire.

One might consider the social class of the people likely to use these implements in an upper-class household in, say, Victorian times. A poker might be used by the owner of the household if he/she did not want to bother a servant. Tongs (to make up a fire) would probably be used by the butler or a maid. Lastly, cleaning out the fire grate would probably be the job of a scullery maid.

Wikipedia has a interesting, albeit short, entry, and gives the earliest known street cry containing the phrase "one or two a penny" a date of 1733 (*Poor Robin's Almanack*). An online currency converter indicates that 1d (one penny) in 1730 would have a purchasing power of about £0.49 (UK) today. Supermarket prices of £0.38 and £0.15 for premium and cheap Hot Cross Buns (Tesco) compare favourably with 1730 street prices. (Thanks to Gareth Rees for this info.)

[Wikipedia : Hot Cross Buns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Cross_Buns)

Comment: Even today, [Tesco has](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/bakery/teacakes-fruit-loaves-and-scones/hot-cross-buns) cheap hot cross buns for 15p, and expensive hot cross buns for 38p.

Comment: @GarethRees And 1d (one penny) in 1900 is equivalent to about 33p today, so it figures.

Comment: Still, I'm definitely going to refer to the 'hot cross bun paradox' in my next treatise, like it's a thing already.

Comment: @Strawberry Everyone loves a paradox, and a conspiracy theory even more. You are going to have to campaign hard to get my exposé deleted, though. 

Comment: The real paradox is what I'm meant to do with them if I don't have daughters or sons.

Comment: @Showsni eat them yourself?